# Can a magnet deflect a static charge? If not, how do photons work?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, charge, relativity, relative-motion

A moving magnet is supposed to generate an electric field.  That implies that a moving magnet should be able to deflect a static charge. Will the charge be deflected?

If it does not deflect a static charge, then where does the electric field in electromagnetic radiation come from?

Comment: According to the Maxwell equations, yes

Comment: A changing magnetic field does not generate an electric field. It _is_ the rotation of an electric field.

Comment: @my2cts, What your saying is wrong... consider a magnet falling in a copper pipe, its not rotating... yet, its generating eddy currents.

Comment: @gyromagnetic I wrote Rotation of an electric field not of a magnet.

Comment: Thanks guys.. @my2cts, what you are saying is what I was thinking.  But a photon in empty space obviously has no charge, and my concern is that rotating a field devoid of charge would not induce a magnetic field, thus breaking the cycle.

Comment: Electromagnetic waves are solution if the mawelk equations without source, that is no charge or current is involved except when they are emitted or absorbed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not only a moving magnet. Any changing magnetc field generates an electric field. This happens in every transformer in your electric appliances.

Your second question is also answered in this way. Any changing magnetic field generates an electric field.

Answer (score 0):

In one reference frame you have a moving charge traveling past a stationary magnet. Therefore, the charge feels a force from the magnet.

In a different reference frame you have a moving magnet traveling past a stationary charge. Due to relativity, the charge must still feel a force. It cannot be the magnetic force in this reference frame, as the charge is stationary. Therefore, it must feel a force due to an electric field.

This is how electromagnetic fields behave between reference frames moving at different velocities relative to each other. This is typically analyzed and described using the [electromagnetic tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor).